# Why is my packer exe not running?

Tags: system-installation, debian

I am running my Kali machine. I downloaded packer for Linux 
I made sym link

```
`~/Downloads ls -s packer /usr/local/bin/packer
```

From root,I try
packer

```
bash: packer: command not found
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Maybe a typing error, but use `ln` (not `ls`)
- I think you intend to use

  ```
  ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
  ```

  according to `man ln`, and I think you need a full path to the target
- Try

  ```
  ln -s "$HOME"/Downloads/packer /usr/local/bin/packer
  ```